# Does it make sense to always use bootstrapping with regression models?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, resampling

I was wondering if there is any reason to not always use bootstrapping when estimating regression coefficients? If I use the full sample, I only get one estimate which might be driven by specific observations in the sample. If I use bootstrapping, however, I can average a lot of estimates and perhaps receive coefficients with less noise. Thus, I am wondering why coefficients in research papers are so seldom reported bootstrapped but rather from a single regression with occasional robustness checks.

Comment: We still have asymptotic theory, get standard errors and all from a "single regression". Bootstrapping is a great tool but it is not an answer for everything. Also, under certain designs (e.g. hierarchical designs) simple bootstrapping it might be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic theory tells us that the variance (or uncertainty) around a coefficient estimate from a regression decreases as the sample grows, therefore, what the theory tells us is that running a regression on the full sample as opposed to smaller bootstrapped samples would give a coefficient estimate with less noise than individual bootstrapped coefficients.

Now, you are saying that averaging over a lot of bootstrapped coefficients would give a less noisy estimate than by running one regression, however an average over the coefficients is in theory an expected value, and so the gauss markov theorem would tell us that the average over a very large number of the bootstrapped samples is in theory the same as the estimate from one regression.

Comment: Thanks already for this answer! I was just wondering, are you by referring to the expected value not only implying that both methods should be unbiased? When thinking of the properties of bootstrap I was thinking of the same relationship between OLS and Weighted Least Squares. Both are unbiased, but WLS has better properties in regard to variance in presence of heteroscedasticity. Thus, I thought it should be the case that the bootstrapped values should in general have better variance properties, especially when using normal non-parametric bootstrap which does not reduce the size of the sample